# Generate human readable list of (non)-subsequent dates

Tags: php

When given a list of n-number of dates which can be subsequent dates are just plain random dates; what is the best way to generate a proper human readable string of it.

Let me give an example:

```
2016-02-13, 2016-02-14, 2016-02-15, 2016-02-16
```

Should be represented as:

```
feb 13th '16 - feb 16th '16
```

Converting the dates to the human readable counterpart is easy; I'm interested in some kind of algorithm to reduce an array of dates to a short as possible solution.

Things start to get difficult when the list contains 'holes':

```
2016-02-13, 2016-02-14, 2016-02-15, 2016-03-02, 2016-03-03

feb 13th '16 - feb 15th '16 & mar 2nd '16 - mar 3rd '16
```

I've been breaking my head over this for some time already; and I didn't got any further then breaking the list, order it, make it unique, see how much days there are in between and check that to see how many elements are in there.

But fixing the 'hole' issue is harder... And my solution is not water tight....

Any thoughts on how to approach this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help of @kay27 introducing the idea of searching for intervals this is how I'm now creating the list of intervals. 
Assuming this is a method within an eloquent model, having a list of data in `$this->data`. And using Carbon to produce nice date-modifiers.

```
public function fd($format = 'Y-m-d')
{
    $dates = [];
    $intervals = [];

    foreach ($this->data as $d) {
        $dates[] = \Carbon::parse($d->datum);
    }
    // sort the dates..


    // init
    $i=0;
    $t=0;
    $peil = $dates[$i];
    $intervals[$t] = [$peil];

    // loop through the dates starting from 0+1, as we already
    // 'processed' the first entry.
    for ($i=1; $i < count($dates); $i++) {
        //  when not equal; then we will need to create a new inTerval,
        //  so we increase the index:
        if ($peil != $dates[$i]->copy()->subDay()) {
            $t++;
        }
        // adding the date to the appropriate interval.
        $intervals[$t][] = $dates[$i];
        // the reference date, as-in the last date added to the list.
        $peil = $dates[$i];
    }


    // do some formatting on the intervals

    return $intervals;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrote in a hurry, so please check carefully, especially daylight saving cases. The main idea is that we need to get intervals:

```
<?php
  date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

  $dates=explode(', ',
  '2015-02-13, 2015-02-14, 2015-02-15, 2015-02-16, 2016-02-13, 2016-02-14, 2016-02-15, 2016-03-02, 2016-03-03');

  $intervals = Array();
  $t0 = -1;
  $t = $t0;

  if(count($dates))
    foreach($dates as $d)
    {
      $t00 = strtotime("$d -1 day");
      if($t != $t00)
      {
        if($t0 != -1)
        {
          if($t == $t0)
            $intervals[]=date("M jS 'y",$t0);
          else
            $intervals[]=date("M jS 'y",$t0) . ' - ' . date("M jS 'y",$t);
        }
        $t = strtotime($d);
        $t0 = $t;
      }
      else
        $t = strtotime($d);
    }

  if ($t0 != $t)
    $intervals[]=date("M jS 'y",$t0) . ' - ' . date("M jS 'y",$t);

  echo join(" & ", $intervals);
```

Result:

```
Feb 13th '15 - Feb 16th '15 & Feb 13th '16 - Feb 15th '16 & Mar 2nd '16 - Mar 3rd '16
```

Comment: This produces a list with 1970 dates... so somewhere there is an error which falls back to the default date()....

Comment: If you will share the sequence that produce an error, it would simplify for me to find it